# Write RFC4180 compatible flat files with less agressive quoting

Tags: r, csv, double-quotes, rfc4180

When using `write.table` or `write.csv` in R, double quotes are added around all non-numeric fields by default regardless of whether the quotes are actually required for proper parsing of the csv file.

Take a Python script as an example:

```
import csv
f_out=open("pytest.csv", "w")
wri = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
wri.writerow(['c_numeric', 'c_str', 'c_str_spec'])
wri.writerow([11, "r1c2", "r1c3 nothing special"])
wri.writerow([21, "r2c2", "r2c3,with delim"])
wri.writerow([31, "r3c2", "r3c3\nwith carriage return"])
wri.writerow([41, "r4c2", "r3c3\"with double quote"])
f_out.close()
```

This will output the following into `pytest.csv`:

```
c_numeric,c_str,c_str_spec
11,r1c2,r1c3 nothing special
21,r2c2,"r2c3,with delim"
31,r3c2,"r3c3
with carriage return"
41,r4c2,"r3c3""with double quote"
```

This is what I expect and follows what Excel will output also.

Now let's process this file using R and write with and without quotes:

```
df <- read.csv("pytest.csv")
write.csv(df, 'Rtest.csv', row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(df, 'Rtest_NQ.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Here is `Rtest.csv`:

```
"c_numeric","c_str","c_str_spec"
11,"r1c2","r1c3 nothing special"
21,"r2c2","r2c3,with delim"
31,"r3c2","r3c3
with carriage return"
41,"r4c2","r3c3""with double quote"
```

Notice the quotes around *all* non-numeric fields.

Here is `Rtest_NQ.csv`:

```
c_numeric,c_str,c_str_spec
11,r1c2,r1c3 nothing special
21,r2c2,r2c3,with delim
31,r3c2,r3c3
with carriage return
41,r4c2,r3c3"with double quote
```

This file is technically corrupt as it's unreadable by any csv reader — so not a good option.

My question: Is there any rfc4180 compatible writer in R that writes like that of Excel or python csv library and most other rfc4180 compatible tools?

Comment: Is there a particular problem with the superfluous quotes? For what it's worth, `pandas.read_csv()` seems to handle this OK by inferring the type column-wise ...

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything against rf4180 here: `Each field **may or may not** be enclosed in double quotes" (emphasis added).

Comment: I use flat files a ton in my daily workflows and have found a need to filter out records based on complex queries. I could not find anything worth while so I wrote such a utility in R and I want the output to follow the most common practices of such tools by avoiding superfluous quotes. FYI - my n00b R script is here: https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/rfilter

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple function to construct a csv by converting the data frame to a character matrix, escaping any double quotes then quoting any strings containing commas or line breaks. You then add the column names and write as csv with `writeLines`

You can even choose a custom delimiter, which will work as long as it is not esoteric enough to be misinterpreted as a regex.

```
write_unquoted <- function(df, path, delim = ",")
{
  regexp <- paste0(delim, "|\n")
  x <- as.matrix(df) 
  x[grep("\"", x)] <- paste0("\"", gsub("\"", "\"\"", x[grep("\"", x)]), "\"")
  x[grep(regexp, x)]  <- paste0("\"", x[grep(regexp, x)], "\"")
  x <- c(paste0(colnames(x), collapse = delim), apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = delim))
  writeLines(x, path)
}
```

So if we start with your example:

```
df
#>   c_numeric c_str                 c_str_spec
#> 1        11  r1c2       r1c3 nothing special
#> 2        21  r2c2            r2c3,with delim
#> 3        31  r3c2 r3c3\nwith carriage return
#> 4        41  r4c2     r3c3"with double quote
```

and we do

```
write_unquoted(df, "my.csv")
```

We can see it faithfully stores the data frame:

```r
identical(read.csv("my.csv"),  df)
#> [1] TRUE
```

and if we look at the produced csv, it looks like this:

```
c_numeric,c_str,c_str_spec
11,r1c2,r1c3 nothing special
21,r2c2,"r2c3,with delim"
31,r3c2,"r3c3
with carriage return"
41,r4c2,"r3c3""with double quote"
```

that is, only quoted when needed.

I don't know if there are any counterexamples where this simple method isn't RFC4180 compatible.

Comment: Thanks Allan. Any chance you could update to allow delim as a parameter of write_unquoted() so it will be compatible other delimiters like tabs?

Comment: Awesome! I'll let this soak for a few days before marking as answered as I'm not technically strong enough to visually assess and don't have time or R knowledge to build a test suite to verify. Hopefully someone else is willing to kick the tires on testing this thoroughly for any possible failure modes ;^]

Comment: I was searching for exhaustive write.table testing under https://github.com/wch/r-source but I could not find anything there that was doing any really hard testing of write.table. I heard that Golang has great testing and confirmed that they have a pretty broad test suite for csv: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/csv/writer_test.go .

Comment: Discovered a potential issue with using other delims. For instance the pipe will not work as-is and would require an escape backslash. I suspect that tab delim would not work as well. Not sure if glob2rx() would work in translating to correct regex.